# Undefer all tables in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is there direct syntax to undefer all columns in a query object?

I know there is a way of undefering groups, but I have a query touching many tables with many groups deferred that I'd like to undefer. It's getting a bit verbose.

I know you can undefer all columns in a single Table, but what about doing it for every Table:

```
# undefer all columns specific to a single class using Load + *
session.query(MyClass, MyOtherClass).options(
    Load(MyClass).undefer("*"))
```

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_columns.html#sqlalchemy.orm.undefer

Comment: manually typing out my Load(TablesClass) as an interim solution. The only other approach I can think of is some hacky list all Tables and append the query object.